# Typescript access extended Class variables

Tags: typescript, class, variables, autocomplete, extends

**My Code**

I have an "Item" class which is extended by other classes that have their own variables, like so:

```
class Item {
  name: string
  symbol: string
  constructor(n: string, s: string){
    this.name = n
    this.symbol = s
  }
}

class Food extends Item {
  type: string
  constructor(n: string, s: string, t: string){
    super(n, s)
    this.type = t
  }
}

class Jewelry extends Item {
  value: number
  constructor(n: string, s: string, v: number){
    super(n, s)
    this.value = v
  }
}
```

I initialize like this:

```
let items: Array<Food | Jewelry> = []

items.push(new Food('Carrot', 'C', 'Vegetable'))
items.push(new Jewelry('Necklace', 'N', 100))
```

**The Problem:**

Now when I type items[0].type, the editor does not recognize the subclass "food" specific variable "type", but only recognizes the parent variables "name" and "symbol". Same with the subclass "jewelry" of course.

It throws me this error:

```
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Food | Jewelry'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Jewelry'.ts(2339)
```

It works as intended if I set the index implicitly like so:

```
items[0] = new Food('Carrot', 'C', 'Vegetable')

items[0].type // => 'Vegetable'
```

Can I access the subclass variables even when adding the Objects through the "push()" method?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the compiler has no idea which object belongs to which type in the array. It does not know that `items[0]` is `Food` and `items[1]` is `Jewelry`. It only knows that all are, in some way, `Item`s, so all you can type-safely use is `item[x].name`, as that's the only common property.

You can, however, support the compiler a bit. For example by checking what class an object belongs to and then working with that additional type safety.

In the following example, I am using `instanceof` to achieve that, and the compiler, now, does not complain about accessing `type` for `Food` objects and `value` for `Jewelry` objects:

```
class Item {
  name: string
  symbol: string
  constructor(n: string, s: string){
    this.name = n
    this.symbol = s
  }
}

class Food extends Item {
  type: string
  constructor(n: string, s: string, t: string){
    super(n, s)
    this.type = t
  }
}

class Jewelry extends Item {
  value: number
  constructor(n: string, s: string, v: number){
    super(n, s)
    this.value = v
  }
}

let items: Array<Food | Jewelry> = []

items.push(new Food('Carrot', 'C', 'Vegetable'))
items.push(new Jewelry('Necklace', 'N', 100))

for (const item of items) {
    if (item instanceof Food) {
        console.log(item.type);
    } else if (item instanceof Jewelry) {
        console.log(item.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, will take your advice and check for instance! Simon